MongoDB cache decorator
I think I cooked again, but maybe not. I'll share with you the product of today's cooking:
@inject.autoparams()
def get_database(client: MongoClient):
    return client["cache"]

lock = threading.Lock()

def _mongocached(func, *args, **kwargs):
    invalid_args = [
        (i, arg) for i, arg in enumerate(args)
        if not isinstance(arg, Hashable) or getattr(type(arg), "__repr__") is object.__repr__
    ]
    
    invalid_kwargs = [
        (k, kwarg) for k, kwarg in kwargs.items()
        if not isinstance(kwarg, Hashable) or getattr(type(kwarg), "__repr__") is object.__repr__
    ]
    
    if invalid_args or invalid_kwargs:
        errors = []
        if invalid_args:
            errors.append("Positional arguments:")
            for index, arg in invalid_args:
                errors.append(f"    Index {index}: {arg} (type: {type(arg).__name__})")
        
        if invalid_kwargs:
            errors.append("Keyword arguments:")
            for key, kwarg in invalid_kwargs:
                errors.append(f"    Key '{key}': {kwarg} (type: {type(kwarg).__name__})")
        
        raise ValueError("The following arguments are not hashable:\n" + "\n".join(errors))

    combined_key = f"{func.__qualname__}{repr(args)}{repr(kwargs)}"
    cache_hash = hashlib.sha256(combined_key.encode()).hexdigest()

    database = get_database()
    cache_collection = database[f"service_{SERVICE_ID}"]

    with lock:
        cached_entry = cache_collection.find_one({"cache_hash": cache_hash})

        if cached_entry:
            entry = CacheEntry(**cached_entry)
            serialized_content = entry.content
            if entry.compressed:
                serialized_content = zlib.decompress(serialized_content)
            return pickle.loads(serialized_content)

        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        serialized_result = pickle.dumps(result)
        is_compressed = len(serialized_result) > 16384
        if is_compressed:
            serialized_result = zlib.compress(serialized_result, level=7)

        new_cache_entry = CacheEntry(
            cache_hash=cache_hash,
            content=serialized_result,
            compressed=is_compressed
        )
        cache_collection.insert_one(new_cache_entry.model_dump())

    return result

def mongocached(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return _mongocached(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def mongocachedmethod(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return _mongocached(method, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper



What y'all think? Is it understandable? Could it be implemented better?
Perchance.
I know someone will say something about the use of repr as a way of hashing the arguments. Well, I know, I know... But are there any better alternatives for consistent caching among multiple application restarts? I think not, but who knows?

I find this to be not very readable. Consider adding a one-sentence """docstring""" when you write a function. And choose better identifiers than e.g. mongocachedmethod. Notice that an f-string treats {repr(args)} and {args!r} identically.

Personally I'd implement these changes:
1) Custom serialization protocol
def serialize_arg(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, (int, str, float, bool)):
        return repr(arg)
    elif isinstance(arg, (list, tuple)):
        return f"({type(arg).__name__})" + ",".join(serialize_arg(x) for x in arg)
    elif isinstance(arg, dict):
        return "{" + ",".join(f"{serialize_arg(k)}:{serialize_arg(v)}" for k,v in sorted(arg.items())) + "}"
    else:
        # Fall back to repr for other types
        return repr(arg)

This approach brings several advantages, like the explicit handling of nested structures, the type preservation in the cache key (type(arg).__name__) and the consistent ordering for dictionaries through sorted().
2) JSON Serialization
def make_cache_key(func, args, kwargs):
    try:
        key_parts = [func.__qualname__, json.dumps(args), json.dumps(kwargs, sort_keys=True)]
        return hashlib.sha256("|".join(key_parts).encode()).hexdigest()
    except TypeError:
        # Fall back to repr if JSON serialization fails
        return hashlib.sha256(f"{func.__qualname__}{repr(args)}{repr(kwargs)}".encode()).hexdigest()

This utility function leverages a standardized serialization format and sort_keys=True guarantees consistent ordering of dictionary keys. The "|" character (pipe) works as separator to prevent key collisions between different parts.
